# _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'Vector'>: attribute lookup Vector on builtins failed

Tags: game-engine, network

i get this error in every time i run my client code i tried to defined mathutils lib but i still get it

> File "Client.py", line 34, in 
>   _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup Vector on builtins failed

```
#------------Setup--------------#
from pickle import dumps, loads
from mathutils import Vector
from GameLogic import * 
import GameLogic as GameLogic
import bge
from socket import *
import socket
import pickle


cont = GameLogic.getCurrentController()
owner = cont.owner
#obj = cont.owner

if not owner['OneTime']:
  ServerIP = GameLogic.IP
  Serverport = 471
  Clientname = ''
  ClientPort = 472
  GameLogic.sClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  GameLogic.sClient.bind((Clientname,ClientPort))
  GameLogic.host = (ServerIP,Serverport)    
  GameLogic.sClient.setblocking(0)
  owner['OneTime'] = 1

PosYou = owner.worldPosition

scene = getCurrentScene()
Server = scene.objects["Server"]

PosServer = [0,0,0]
#------------RECEIVE/SEND--------------#    
Data = pickle.dumps((PosYou))
GameLogic.sClient.sendto(Data,GameLogic.host)

try:
    Data, SRIP = GameLogic.sClient.recvfrom(1024)
    UPData = pickle.loads(Data)
    PosServer = [UPData[0],UPData[1],UPData[2]]
    Server.setPosition(PosServer)
except:
    pass            
#---------------THE-END----------------#
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert the vector to list

```
picklablePosition = list(owner.worldPosition)
```

and back

```
unpickledPositionAsList = [UPData[0],UPData[1],UPData[2]]
owner.worldPosition = unpickledPositionAsList # worldPosition accepts a 3-tuple list
```

Comment: so that what you mean changing PosYou = owner.worldPosition
to PosYou = list(owner.worldPosition) 
and set  PosServer = [UPData[0],UPData[1],UPData[2]] and adding this line owner.worldPosition = PosServer ?

Comment: Have the same problem. But I am using a lot of Vectors (they are convenient for operations), and it would be very difficult to convert all of them before pickling. Should I make a custom Vector class to solve a problem?

Comment: As you can't pickle mathutils.Vector directly you need to convert it to an object that can be pickled. This also means you need to convert it back after un-pickle.If you create a custom object or use a plain List does not really matter.

Comment: Why is it difficult to convert the data you want to pickle?

Comment: @Monster Because I have used a lot of vectors in a lot of different objects holding hierarchical references to each other. I am lazy to find and listicize them all. But surely, it is doable.

Comment: @Monster Meanwhile I have found that including 'class Vector(mathutils.Vector): pass' in the main text of the module, and using the new subclass of vector instead of the original does not raise the exception, but the unpickled Vector becomes null-vector. Is there no way to make it work along these lines?

Comment: I recommend to convert the complete structure (by traversing through all the linked elements). I think you need to do this anyway as you need a way to store and restore these relationships too. Otherwise you do not know where to apply the transferred data too.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working by inheritting and overriding as suggested by @b.Lorenz, then using copyreg to specify the pickling behaviour (I had no luck with **setstate** and **getstate**).

Also did this for mathutils.Euler & mathutils.Quaternion, and overrided a couple of the conversion functions to have them return the new types (to avoid having to wrap around these calls in the code). Add these as needed, any bugs will probably come from a function generating the mathutils type (I had to override Matrix.to_euler() even though I had no interest in pickling it).

The overriding has to be done in a separate file otherwise the pickling works when the script is first run (as the test on this does), but not for routines triggered by button presses etc.. these give a pickle error about not finding type definition Vector in **main**.
I guess when a script finishes execution there's some cleanup behaviour which removes the pickling definitions so they dont persist after plugin registration.

Importing the types from a separate .py file wherever needed seems avoid this.

Here's **picklables.py** with the new types to import:

```
import bpy, pickle, copyreg, mathutils

### overriden mathutils types & conversion functions
class Vector(mathutils.Vector): pass

class Quaternion(mathutils.Quaternion):
    def to_euler(self, order='XYZ'): return Euler(super().to_euler(order))

class Euler(mathutils.Euler):
    def to_quaternion(self): return Quaternion(super().to_quaternion())

class Matrix(mathutils.Matrix):
    def to_quaternion(self): return Quaternion(super().to_quaternion())

### hidden functions to tell pickle how to pickle
def _pickle_vector(vec): return Vector, (vec[:],)
copyreg.pickle(Vector, _pickle_vector)

def _pickle_quat(quat): return Quaternion, (quat[:],)
copyreg.pickle(Quaternion, _pickle_quat)

def _pickle_euler(euler): return Euler, (euler[:], euler.order)
copyreg.pickle(Euler, _pickle_euler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        a.append((  Quaternion((1,2,3,4)),
                    Vector((3,4,5)),
                    Euler((1,2,3), 'XYZ'),
                    Euler((1,2,3), 'ZYX'),
                    Quaternion((1,2,3,4)).to_euler(),
                    Euler((1,2,3), 'XYZ').to_quaternion()))

    print('Saving types..'); file = open(bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath+'\\..\\vpickle_test.txt', 'wb'); pickle.dump(a, file); file.close()

    try: file = open(bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath+'\\..\\vpickle_test.txt', 'rb'); b = pickle.load(file); file.close(); print('Loaded types'); print(b[0])
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```